# $project, $lookup for multiple fields

Tags: swift, mongodb

How can I project limited fields from multiple collections? I have three collections and I am using $lookup, $project. Out of three I am only able to limit the fields for one collection using $project. Rest two are coming as a whole object, when I only need 3 to 4 fields from them.

```
       let bsonMatch = BSON()
            bsonMatch.append(key: jsonConstants.email, string: emailAddress)

            let match = BSON()
            match.append(key: "$match", document: bsonMatch)


        bsonFields.append(key: jsonConstants.email, int: 1)
        bsonFields.append(key: jsonConstants.compId, int: 1)
        bsonFields.append(key: jsonConstants.role, int: 1)
        bsonFields.append(key: jsonConstants.fullName, int: 1)
        bsonFields.append(key: jsonConstants.mobile, int: 1)
        bsonFields.append(key: jsonConstants.homeTele, int: 1)
        bsonFields.append(key: jsonConstants.zipCode, int: 1)
        bsonFields.append(key: jsonConstants.gender, int: 1)




        let compObject = BSON ()

            compObject.append(key: jsonConstants.compName, int: 1)
            compObject.append(key: jsonConstants.compId, int: 1)
            compObject.append(key: jsonConstants.compAddress, int: 1)



            let compProject = BSON ()

            compProject.append(key: "$project", document: compObject)

        let compLookup = BSON ()

            compLookup.append(key: "from", string: dbTableConstants.companyTable)
            compLookup.append(key: "localField", string: jsonConstants.compId)
            compLookup.append(key: "foreignField", string: jsonConstants.compId)
            compLookup.append(key: "as", string: "company")






            let lookup = BSON()
            lookup.append(key: "$lookup", document: bsonLookUp)



            let compBson = BSON ()

            compBson.append(key: "$lookup", document: compLookup)


            var bsonQuery = BSON()
            bsonQuery.append(key: "0", document: match)
            bsonQuery.append(key: "1", document: project)
            bsonQuery.append(key: "2", document: lookup)
        //  bsonQuery.append(key: "3", document: compBson)
            bsonQuery.append(key: "3", document: compLookup)





            let pipline = try? BSON(json: bsonQuery.asArrayString)

            print(bsonQuery.asArrayString)

            guard let serverResult = userCollection.aggregate(pipeline: pipline!) else{
                response.setBody(string: responseMsg(msg: msgConstants.internalServerError, success: false))
                response.status = HTTPResponseStatus.internalServerError
                response.completed()
                return

            }
```

In this snippet I have only given two collections, I want both these collections to project only selective fields.
The first projection is the usertable, and the other is the company table. Relation : user belongs to a particular company. So I need the necessary company's details for that particular user.

Comment: could you please paste your code... that would make it a lot easier

Comment: please check. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what I was missing. The fields, even from multiple collections are needed to be in one $project operation. We can lookup into multiple tables and can then append our selective fields from each table to project.
So the above code will be:

```
       let bsonMatch = BSON()
        bsonMatch.append(key: jsonConstants.email, string: emailAddress)

        let match = BSON()
        match.append(key: "$match", document: bsonMatch)


    bsonFields.append(key: jsonConstants.email, int: 1)
    bsonFields.append(key: jsonConstants.compId, int: 1)
    bsonFields.append(key: jsonConstants.role, int: 1)
    bsonFields.append(key: jsonConstants.fullName, int: 1)
    bsonFields.append(key: jsonConstants.mobile, int: 1)
    bsonFields.append(key: jsonConstants.homeTele, int: 1)
    bsonFields.append(key: jsonConstants.zipCode, int: 1)
    bsonFields.append(key: jsonConstants.gender, int: 1)




    let compObject = BSON ()

        compObject.append(key: jsonConstants.compName, int: 1)
        compObject.append(key: jsonConstants.compId, int: 1)
        compObject.append(key: jsonConstants.compAddress, int: 1)





    let compLookup = BSON ()

        compLookup.append(key: "from", string: dbTableConstants.companyTable)
        compLookup.append(key: "localField", string: jsonConstants.compId)
        compLookup.append(key: "foreignField", string: jsonConstants.compId)
        compLookup.append(key: "as", string: "company")

        bsonFields.append(key: "company", document: compObject)

  let project = BSON()
            project.append(key: "$project", document: bsonFields)

        let lookup = BSON()
        lookup.append(key: "$lookup", document: bsonLookUp)



        let compBson = BSON ()

        compBson.append(key: "$lookup", document: compLookup)


        var bsonQuery = BSON()
        bsonQuery.append(key: "0", document: match)
        bsonQuery.append(key: "1", document: compBson)
        bsonQuery.append(key: "2", document: project)








        let pipline = try? BSON(json: bsonQuery.asArrayString)

        print(bsonQuery.asArrayString)

        guard let serverResult = userCollection.aggregate(pipeline: pipline!) else{
            response.setBody(string: responseMsg(msg: msgConstants.internalServerError, success: false))
            response.status = HTTPResponseStatus.internalServerError
            response.completed()
            return

        }
```